# Closing file attached to email System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, system.net.mail

I have a file I attach to email in an ASP.NET application. The problem is that the process will not let go of the file. How do I close the file in the method so I can use it in my program again?

```
Attachment data = new Attachment(@"\\WIN-UWPWZ7Z3RKX\wwwroot\katipro\skus.txt");
m.Attachments.Add(data); 

SmtpClient s = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
s.Send(m);
```

After I call the method it does not allow me to write to that file again without an error.

Comment: As @Sam mentioned below it's enough to dispose MailMessage. Accepted answer will be hard to maintain if you have multiple attachments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.Net.Mail.Attachment` implements [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144637.aspx). You need to dispose your attachment.

```
using(Attachment data = new Attachment(@"\\WIN-UWPWZ7Z3RKX\wwwroot\katipro\skus.txt"))
{
    m.Attachments.Add(data); 

    SmtpClient s = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    s.Send(m);
}
```

Likewise, if you are using .NET Framework 4.0; `SmtpClient` is disposable as well. So dispose of it if you are using the 4.0 Framework. You should *always* dispose of things that implement the IDisposable interface when you are done using them.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to dispose the attachments when you dispose the MailMessage. If you look at the internal implementation, the MailMessage does already dispose the attachments itself.

```
// MailMessage.cs
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !disposed)
        {
            disposed = true;

            if(views != null){
                views.Dispose();
            }
            if(attachments != null){
                attachments.Dispose();
            }
            if(bodyView != null){
                bodyView.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Code from https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System

Answer (score 2):

You need to dispose all `IDisposable` objects you use for them to release unmanaged resources such as file handles.

```
using(MailMessage m = ...)
{
    ...
    using (Attachment data = ...)
    { 
        ...
        using (SmtpClient s = ...)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Attachment` implements `IDisposable`; you need to dispose the instance to release its resources, after you send the message.

```
...
s.Send(m)

data.Dispose();
```